# issue with wifi EEPROM country

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

I am getting the following errors with version 22.04 to access internet:

```
[  582.990377] wlp13s0: associated
[  582.991527] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x80fa
[  582.991537] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  582.991542] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  582.991546] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  582.991551] ath: Country alpha2 being used: FR
[  582.991555] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  582.991559] ath: regdomain 0x80fa dynamically updated by country element
```

It breaks the wifi connection.

I have tried to run `iw reg set FR` but it does not seem to have effect.
And I would like to have a solution that runs after the reboot.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you thinking that "It breaks the wifi connection"? Your log shows that regdomain is correct.

Comment: I don't see any error in your readings. These are informational. If your wifi connection breaks, this is not the reason. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.